# openssl and ruby error when using vagrant

Tags: libvirt, vagrant

I use `CentOS 8.4, libvirtd (libvirt) 6.0.0, Vagrant 2.2.18, gem version 2.7.6.3 and ruby 2.5.9p229 (2021-04-05 revision 67939) [x86_64-linux]`

I am trying to use vagrant to build VM's on Qemu/KVM. Technically, KVM is running fine and I am manually able to create VM's. It's just that, I am unable to create VM's using vagrant. I installed vagrant and vagrant plugin for libvirt. Version is:  `vagrant-libvirt (0.5.3, global)`

I tried to bring up vagrant using this command `vagrant up --provider=libvirt` and got error as

```
/usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3: undefined symbol: EVP_KDF_ctrl, version OPENSSL_1_1_1b - /home/user/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.4/gems/ruby-libvirt-0.7.1/lib/_libvirt.so (LoadError)
```

I use OpenSSL version as  `1.1.1g FIPS  21 Apr 2020`

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution, but I'll share additional details here that won't fit in a comment.

- vabrant-libvirt is a plugin that's community maintained (and they've been asking for maintainers for a while, https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt/issues/1069, which is probably why it hasn't been properly fixed for so long). Since it's not  maintained by Hashicorp, it's not as well supported as Vagrant in general.
- The RHEL8 variants have been broken/glitchy for about a year now, so unless you have solid dev chops your options are as follows:

  1. Try all the tips here https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt#possible-problems-with-plugin-installation-on-linux
  2. read through bug reports (many were closed w/o resolution, often because they were posted on the wrong repo https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues) submit a bug report https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt/issues
  3. Consider switching distros. (Centos 7 doesn't EoL until Jun 2024/another 2.4 years, by the time it EOLs, this issue would probably be fixed for Centos 8. and there's always the option to switch to something like Debian, SUSE)

I run into the same issue using:

- AlmaLinux 8.5 (which seems true to the advertised claim of being "bug for bug compatible" with RHEL 8.5 ;))
- Vagrant 2.2.19
- I had to run `CONFIGURE_ARGS="..." vagrant plugin install vagrant-libvirt`, in order to see your error, but afterwards ended up stuck in the same spot.

Seems to be a unresolved bug related to how openssl is bundled per this source: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1925782

> This kind of thing usually happens when someone else embeds their own
> copy of openssl and it doesn't have the same symbols that the system
> one does.  In this case, it looks like your copy of vagrant bundles
> its own openssl (!):
>
> $ rpm -ql ./vagrant_2.2.14_x86_64.rpm | grep crypto.so
> /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib64/libcrypto.so
> /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1 $
>
> This is an external package; we didn't provide it.  We did provide a
> system openssl (we think it's pretty good), and the package should be
> using that, not embedding its own thing.  In particular, it needs to
> not be overriding the system libraries with its own when it calls out
> to other system functionality, like that using krb5.

Seems to be an unresolved issue that's been going on for a while as there's multiple issue tickets on it.
https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt/issues/1088#issuecomment-686513145